# Кащей Бессмертный в славянских языках

Tags: переводы

Как известно, персонаж русских сказок Кощей Бессмертный появился до того, как возникло четкое разделение на русский и украинский языки. Но я из школьных лет помню, как дети хихикали: "А ты знаешь, что "Кощей Бессмертный" по-украински будет "Чахлик Невмерущiй"?"
Мне в такое, конечно, не верилось. Но вот тогда интересно, а переводятся ли как-то имена персонажей русских сказок на другие славянские языки? 
Извините, если вопрос не по теме форума, но было бы интересно узнать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но я из школьных лет помню, как дети хихикали: "А ты знаешь, что "Кощей Бессмертный" по-украински будет "Чахлик Невмерущiй"?"

Это больше из области школьных шуточек и баек. :-) Забавно, как они, эти шуточки по много лет остаются на уровне, скажем, всё новых и новых поколений семиклассников. Дети взрослеют, такой юмор им становится неинтересным, а новые дети подхватывают и повторяют те же шутки. Сам слышал как-то от играющих на спортплощадке старшеклассников полузабытые шутки из моего школьного детства.

Вернусь к обсуждению "перевода" имени Кощея. Это такой школьный ряд шуток. 
А как по-украински Александр Пушкин? Сашко Гарматкин! А Лев Толстой? Лэв ГладкЫй! :-) Может быть, что ещё, не припомню. Ну для примера достаточно.

**На самом деле**, это всё будет так же или почти так же, как и на русском:
**Кощiй Безсмертний, Олександр Пушкин, Лев Толстой.**

В других славянских языках, насколько я знаю, имя *Кощей* или так и пишут **Кощей**, или я ещё видел вариант **Костей** (чехи, словаки).

И добавлю, что слово *Бессмертный* обычно **переводится** на соответствующий язык.
Например, по-польски: *Kościej Nieśmiertelny*

Comment: Вспомнил слово, которое иногда употребляется на Украине, -- **кощАвый**. 
Т.е. костлявый, худой, сухощавый.

Ссылка на словарь:  
http://language.br.com.ua/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9/

Кощей -- костлявый, худой?

Comment: @Nikolja В древних текстах слово "кощей" используется в значении "невольник" (от тюркского kоš «лагерь, стоянка»). Значение "костлявый" могло произойти в результате "объединения" значений.